# Как пользоваться Terminus Pantheon

Tags: drupal

https://pantheon.io/ - хостинг и инструменты веб-разработки для команд.
Terminus это инструмент, который позволяет соединиться с этим хостингом, работать с его репозиториями, управлять деплоем.
Как его установить и как в нем работать с git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как установить можно прочитать здесь https://pantheon.io/docs/terminus/install/

Это утилита в командной строке которая позволяет управлять своим хотингом на Pantheon. Перед установкой нужно проверить Requirements, все ли обезательные елементы присутсвуют в локальной системе. На момент ответа это были

```
- PHP Version 5.5.9 or later 
- PHP-CLI
- PHP-CURL
- Composer
```

Дальше нужно в директории в которой у вас есть права на запись выполнить команду скачивания и установкиt, я обычно ставлю в /opt

```
$ mkdir /opt/terminus
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/terminus
$ cd /opt/terminus
```

команды скачивания утилиты и запуска скрипта установки

```
$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pantheon-systems/terminus-installer/master/builds/installer.phar
$ php installer.phar install
```

Мне выдало сообщение

> You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
>
> **Перевод**
>   Вы используете композитор с включенным xdebug. Это оказывает существенное влияние на производительность во время выполнения. См.

Думаю это никак не повлияет на работу `terminus`. Еще много возможных предупреждений и ошибок размотрено https://pantheon.io/docs/terminus/install/ здесь внизу

Алиас у меня не создало само и я получил

```
terminus: command not found
```

Поэтому алиас я создал вручную,

```
$ alias terminus=/opt/terminus/vendor/bin/terminus
```

По завершении установки вы можете протестировать его, выполнив следующую команду:

```
$ terminus art
```

Дальше переходим в директорию где вы будете поднимать сайт локально

```
$ cd /var/<site>
$ git init
```

Давайте возьмем URL-адрес репозитория сайта на Pantheon, используя Terminus. Замените  на имя вашего сайта:

```
$ terminus connection:info <site>.dev --field=git_url
```

Вам выведеться `<git_url>`

```
$ git remote add pantheon <git_url>
$ git pull pantheon
```

Смотрим какие ветки имеються, и переключаемся в нужную ветку

```
$ git branch
$ git checkout master
```

После push в эту ветку код попадет на dev откуда вы его должны будете деплоить на test и live, это можно будет делать с админки Pantheon или же с консоли командами которые сможете найти здесь https://pantheon.io/docs/terminus/commands/

Ошибка 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver.$ENV.$SITE.drush.in' (111)

Эта ошибка возникает, когда запрос отправляется на сервер базы данных, находящийся в спящем режиме. 
[Troubleshooting MySQL Connections](https://pantheon.io/docs/mysql-access/)